# bound norm of algebraic integers in cyclotomic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, norms, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\zeta$ be the $p$th root of unity, with $p$ an odd prime number.

Let $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ be the $p$th cyclotomic field and let $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}(\zeta)$ the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.
Let $u$ be a unit in $\mathcal{O}$, with $u \ne \zeta$.

I'm struggling to find a lower bound for the algebraic integer $\alpha = \zeta - 2 u$. In particular it should be easy to show that $N(\alpha) > 1$, thus $\alpha$ is not a unit.

Letting $p(x)$ the the minimal polynomial for $u$, there should be some way to bound the discriminant of the minimal polynomial for $2 u - \zeta$.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is obviously wrong if $u = \zeta$.

Comment: Of course.
I'll edit the question specifying "excluding trivial cases".

Comment: Is there any reason why your claim should be true? Or interesting?

Comment: $p=5$ and $u=(\zeta+1)^2$ is the easiest example (of many) that $u$ can be a unit while $\zeta-2u$ is a unit, too.